# Bootstrap: Changing column order

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap. I've a problem in changing order of columns in small screens. It should look like below. Any ideas?

**md & lg**

```
[a] [b]

[c] [d]
```

**sm & xs**

```
[A]

[b]

[d]

[c]
```

I've tried push pull combination only for 'sm' but it changing for the other screen sizes 'md' & 'lg'..

```css
.new_section {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.about_bg {
  background-color: rgba(252, 160, 0, 0.76);
}
.jumbo_text > h1 {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.jumbo_text > p {
  color: #666666;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.arch_prof_bg {
  background-color: rgba(252, 160, 0, 0.76);
}
.proj_heading_bg {
  background-color: rgba(129, 86, 11, 0.8);
}
.proj_heading_bg > h1 {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<section class="new_section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="about">
      <div class="col-md-6 jumbo_text about_bg">
        <h1>Our Company</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 jumbo_text">
        <P class="text-left">
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
          content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
          versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </P>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="arch_prof">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 jumbo_text">
        <P class="text-left">
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
          content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
          versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
        </P>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 jumbo_text arch_prof_bg">
        <h1>Architect Profile</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here is something*

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HXgF9ZJpN5)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">D</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">C</div>
</div>
```